# How do I find out where one line crosses another with pandas/matplotlib?

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I've got a data frame called `df['x']` that I have used Matplotlib to graph as shown below. The data frame has a date time index and it fluctuates between being 0 and above 0. There are also two purple lines y=2 and y=5.

I'm interested in finding the dates on the index that the blue line crosses the purple line y=2 when going upward. However with one caveat, if the blue line crosses the purple line going up for a second time before reaching 0 I would not like it to be counted. So I'm looking for a system that returns me 6 dates. Thanks for any help.

https://gyazo.com/40aac726ef3546c22c9191fa2d9bc3e2
[image: Text]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up trying a bunch of different things. Initially I really wasn't sure how to approach this problem because I'm fairly new to coding. After doing a bit of research I found a solution that works by applying a function to create a new column, then finding the index of the areas of the column that meet a certain criteria.

```
#Making a function to apply to df
trade_pos = ''
dip = ''
def apply_function(df):
    global trade_pos
    global dip
    if df.Drawdown == 0 and trade_pos == 'open':
        trade_pos = 'closed'
        dip = 'false'
        return 'Exit'
    elif df.Drawdown == 0:
        trade_pos = 'closed'
        dip = 'false'
        return 0
    elif df.Drawdown >= 2 and df.Drawdown < 5 and trade_pos == 'closed' and dip != 'true':
        trade_pos = 'open'
        return 'Entry'
    elif df.Drawdown >=5 and trade_pos == 'open':
        trade_pos = 'closed'
        dip = 'true'
        return 'Exit'
    else:
        return 0

#Applying function to df
df['Strategy'] = df.apply(apply_function, axis=1)

Finding dates of crossover with caveats
entry = df[df['Strategy'] == 'Entry']
entry = list(entry.index)
#We finish with a list of dates that meet the criteria of the original post
```

I hope that helps anybody else with a similar problem.